# Electrical Help: Swap 50A Range for separate Cooktop & insert Oven (30A each)

Tags: electrical, appliances, 240v, junction-box

House has a 50A, 3-line service to the old Range.

Want to instead have a separate Cooktop and an insert Oven located below it for a sleeker more integrated look. Each have a 30A requirement.

Can they both connect to the 50A feeder?

We have no good way to replace it with 2 separate circuits without replacing the whole electrical panel, and massive damage to ceilings, etc. to get it there.

Is it possible to share?

A range would have just as many burners and an oven on that same circuit, so it seems plausible.
Could replace the 30A cords on the appliance with 50A?  Or is it possible to fuse the 30A appliance cords in the J-Box before connecting to 50A home run?
(We'd need the J-box concealed in the cabinet, so a sub-panel option wouldn't work.)

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. At a minimum, a clear, focused picture of your breaker panel would help - the electricians here are quite good at coming up with possibilities that may not have occurred to you, but they need to at least _see_ what they've got to work with.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the range's junction box? Is replacing the existing cable run or running a cable back to the panel by another route in the cards?

Comment: Do you know if this is "3 wires and that's it" - which means hot/hot/neutral+ground-together - or if it is "3 wires plus either a separate bare-so-don't-count-it-the-same or metal-conduit-which-handles-ground"? That makes a **big** difference. If you're not sure, pictures of junction boxes would help.

Comment: This is a "3 wires and that's it".  No separate ground.    Trying desperately to avoid a new line because there is no way to get it there. Timber-framed with car-decking floors leaves nowhere to hide wires. Exterior walls are CMU. The existing wires must have been routed into a channel in the beams before the floor went on, because there is nowhere else to hide them. We've spent hours contemplating how to run a cable, but short of seeing it exposed, there is no good way. Electrical panel is full, no way to add a new double-pole breaker.

Comment: @Blobfish -- can you find anywhere near the range that has space for a subpanel? And how is the cable constructed for that matter? (Three insulated wires? Two insulated wires and a bare solid ground that's skinnier? Two insulated wires with strands of the ground wire wrapped around them then twisted together into a ground lead at the junction box?)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no, not really since a subpanel needs the access and clearances.  Wall of cabinets, prominent to the kitchen/living area, with nowhere to put anything we can't hide inside a cabinet.  Wires are all insulated.  White, Black and Red.  All stranded, but I haven't determined the exact size yet. In discussion below, I suggested adding a ground out of the wall to a rod to bring it up to standards since getting a ground back to the panel is a problem.  What do you think of that?

Comment: @Blobfish -- a rod does you not a whit of good here.  HOWEVER: can you find a path back to the wire that connects your panel *to* your water pipe and/or ground rods, and is sacrificing a little-used cabinet near the range an option, for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I could get a wire to a pipe no problem, just not back to the panel across the house.  But I'm confused - a ground is a ground.  The panel's ground is simply a cable to a ground rod or rods.  Why wouldn't a separate ground rod achieve the same goal?  Takes it to the earth if things go wrong, right?

Comment: @Blobfish -- no, what you want to do is take the errant utility electricity *back to the utility* as current flows in loops.  You also don't want to take it back to a pipe since some plumber might insert plastic pipe in the way of that path.  Hence, the need to find that wire going back to the ground rods, as dirt is a quite poor conductor of electricity compared to copper

Comment: @Blobfish -- as to sacrificing that cabinet near the range?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Well, no, I just can't do that without ruining the kitchen. There is no way I'm going to interrupt a wall of cabinets with a subpanel.  You can't hide those inside a cabinet, and you need code clearances around them.  This is a tight kitchen as is - can't lose 30" of cabinet top & bottom for a panel.  Also, while I really do appreciate the advice, I'm not buying the grounding rod statement above. Maybe I didn't explain what I'm thinking very well. The grounding at the panel is a grounding bus to a copper wire to grounding rods in the dirt.  (too long - see next comment)

Comment: There is no magic about those grounding rods that I can't replicate with identical wire and grounding rods in a separate place. Right? In both cases I'm literally just connecting the ground wire to a copper cable out to the rod(s) in the dirt. Besides, Code lets me get away with the existing 3-wire, according to the others in this thread who have quoted chapter.  Adding a non-required ground seems like being extra safe, correct?  Nothing will even use that ground unless there is a short to the metal of the appliance and it could save a life. Is this a better; How does this sound to you?

Comment: @Blobfish -- the "magic" about what I'm asking you to do with the rods isn't in that specific set of rods, it's about the *grounding bus* to the *panel* (apologies for not being clear earlier).

Comment: @Blobfish -- the trick with sacrificing the cabinet to the subpanel is that the subpanel flush mounts into the cabinet front, with the other gadget involved (a transformer) parked behind it.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks - you given me some things to ponder and read up on.  Thanks

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  Ah, I see now - grounding alone does not save you, it is the ground that is connected to the neutral at the panel which will cause the breaker to trip. An "effective ground-fault current path".  Thanks for teaching me something.  Question: if I can run a ground wire over to the hot water heater, can I attach to that grounding wire to accomplish the same goal?  Or is sharing a ground on a separate circuit not allowed

Comment: @Blobfish -- as long as the grounding wire for the hot water heater is #10 or larger (which would be true for a typical electric water heater's branch circuit), you're OK to go ahead and do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually with no structural changes it may be a redecorating project. In several states that I have lived many people doing cosmetic updates like your project do not know the proper terms.

With the wrong term they end up doing way more than what is required.

for example in my current state if the receptacle is not moved more than 6’ the original wiring is allowed (we are on the 17 code with state exceptions until April).
In this case if the wiring is properly sized a large junction box being tapped for both devices MAY be acceptable is the box accessible after the work is complete? it all goes back to the AHJ so the location would be needed to know for sure but when the home was built the tap that you want was acceptable see NEC 210.19.3  and for a picture see exhibit 210.24. Last if tapped from the junction box to the next device usually requires conduit.

I do agree with most of Retired master electricians answer but the jurisdiction here is a big deal and I would not be pulling a new feeder if I could be in compliance with my state requirements. If you happened to have 3 insulated conductors (unlikely but possible) pulling a single ground wire I would do to bring up to the current code.

Comment: Notwithstanding the issues of the neutral, NEC otherwise allows oven+cooktop to share a circuit, and it's common enough that people replace a range with a cooktop+oven combination.  220.55 has the table - for two appliances at 30A (7.2kW each) it falls in column 2 (3.5-8kW) allowing a demand derate of 65% for a total (derated) demand of 9.4kW (less than the 11kW max derate demand), so I think this is fine.

Comment: Thank you both!  Very very helpful.  Would it be ok, or better at least, if I add a ground wire straight out to a new ground rod?  I don't have any good way to get a new wire back to the panel.

Comment: @j... I agree yes we can derate. However a few years back a restaurant was wired to code the minimum allowed. It was rebuilt again to the minimum allowed code and it burned down again. The insurance did not want to pay again but needed up on the hook.  I like to know the actual wattages and uses planned usage before going whole hog with the derate (they always want to add or a piece of equipment comes in a kw higher than estimated. Leaving some wiggle room is usually a good idea but yes we can derate.+

Comment: Blobfish I did not see what you have. A hot hot neutral all insulated then yes it is appropriate to take a ground back to the rod if it is closer or easier to get to than the panel. This is a new allowed method of adding a ground. If your existing conductor is not insulated it really won’t help. If any answers or comments are helpful upvote or accept that helps others find them.

Comment: @EdBeal Yeah, a restaurant is obviously a different situation.  There's only so much cooking a residential kitchen is realistically going to do.  I think the same logic allows 50A to service a 12kW range (when really only 9.6kW is available).  Home cooks simply don't go for the five-burner high-heat sear while broiling in the oven at the same time.

Comment: @j,,, you haven’t seen my wife’s final kitchen plan. LOL we had to convert to gas or bump the service to 400a.

Comment: @EdBeal Well, at some point, you just can't get that 100kBTU wok-burner heat with an electric element!

Comment: Realize I should have said "... *40A* to service a 12kW range" above.

Comment: This is a great forum.  Y'all rule.  Thanks again for the excellent feedback, and humor to boot.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to your question.

First you can run a 50A circuit to the kitchen and tap the circuit and run one tap to the cooktop and one tap to the oven. So long as both tap conductors are over 20A and the circuit cannot exceed a 50A supply. I found this in the 2020 NEC Handbook (A)(3) Exception #1.

The real problem is you feeder is a 3 wire which means it shares the neutral and ground conductor and this is no longer allowed. Since this is a remodel you must bring the feeders to all equipment up to the newest code. You can reuse the 50A 2Pole breaker for the range feeder but you must replace the old cable with a new #6-4 wire feeder (2 hots, 1 neutral, and 1 ground).

If you feel you need more clarification. I would advise you to check with you local inspector (AHJ) and see what they have to say.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Keep in mind that we have not established that OP understands what "3-wire" means or that they have used the term correctly in their question.

Comment: Thank you.  I do understand the 3-wire vs 4-wire.  As explained above in a comment, any wires run back to the panel would have to be exposed - nowhere to hide in a post-& beam home - so I ask the following possible solution:  Can I run a ground out the wall to a ground rod instead of back to the panel?